# Should implicitly generated assignment operators be & ref-qualified?

Tags: c++, c++11, assignment-operator, rvalue-reference, rvalue

The following code compiles without problem on gcc 4.8.1:

```
#include <utility>

struct foo
{
};

int main()
{
    foo bar;

    foo() = bar;
    foo() = std::move( bar );
}
```

It seems the implicitly generated assignment operators for `foo` are not `&` ref-qualified and so can be invoked on rvalues.  Is this correct according to the standard?  If so, what reason is there for *not* requiring implicitly generated assignment operators to be `&` ref-qualified?

Why doesn't the standard require the following to be generated?

```
struct foo
{
  foo & operator=( foo const & ) &;

  foo & operator=( foo && ) &;
};
```

Comment: Keep in mind there were implicit copy assignment operators before there was C++11, and thus before there were ref-qualifiers for non-static member functions. That and the philosophy of the Standard Committee when it comes to compiling former C++ code with a newer compiler.

Comment: @Luc For some reason backwards compatibility didn't occur to me until after I'd posted the question.  I'd forgotten that typical cost/benefit analysis doesn't apply when considering changes to the standard.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007802/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there are certain legitimate use cases for assigning to an rvalue.  To quote from [**Ref-qualifiers for assignment operators in the Standard Library:**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2819.html)

> There are only a few very specific types for which it makes sense to
>   support assigning to an rvalue. In particular, types that serve as a
>   proxy, e.g., vector<bool>::reference, and types whose assignment
>   operators are const-qualified (e.g., slice_array).

The C++ standard committee obviously felt that default assignment should not have an implicit ref qualifier - rather it should be *explicitly declared*.  Indeed, there may be existing code which would stop working if all of a sudden all implicitly declared assignment operators didn't work with rvalues.

Granted, it's a bit hard to contrive an example where we want an implicitly declared assignment operator to work with rvalues, but the C++ standard committee likely doesn't want to take these kind of chances when it comes to preserving backwards compatibility.  Code like this:

```
int foo_counter = 0;

struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        ++foo_counter;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        --foo_counter;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo() = Foo();
}
```

...wouldn't work anymore.  And at the end of the day, the standards committee wants to make sure that previously valid C++ (no matter how stupid or contrived) continues to work in C++11.

Comment: It seems they've applied the same logic (re: backwards compatibility) to the linked proposal since the issue was closed as "not a defect."  So all instances of `std::string() = std::string()` will remain valid (for better or worse).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your question is more "*Why would assignment to an rvalue ever be useful?*" rather than "*Why doesn't the standard ref-qualify auto generated constructors?*"

The reason assignment to an rvalue is allowed is because there are some cases where it is useful.

One example usage is with [`std::tie` (link)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
#include <set>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s;

    std::set<int>::iterator iter;
    bool inserted;

    // unpacks the return value of insert into iter and inserted
    std::tie(iter, inserted) = s.insert(7);
}
```

*Example borrowed from cppreference.com then modified*

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question because the OP is specifically asking about implicitly declared assignment operators, not assigning to rvalues in general

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Hmm maybe you're right. I answered in a hurry and slightly misunderstood the question. Your answer more directly answers it.