# Why declare a deleted assignment operators with the ref-qualifier &

Tags: c++, c++14

As far as I know a user declared assignment operators differ from built-in operators, as explained by [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16995559/3054219). But why should one add the "&" to a deleted operator?

```
// C++
class MyType
{
public:
 // ...

  MyType& operator=(MyType const&) & = delete;
  MyType& operator=(MyType &&) & noexcept = default;

// more
};
```

I ask because my static code checker reports a rule violation here and I see no reason to add the "&" for a deleted operator. Do I miss something?

Comment: Which static checker and what is the supposed violation?

Comment: @luk32
We get it with Polyspace when following Autosar C++14 rules

Comment: @luk32 I guess you will get the finding reported (for the default'ed operator) by all static analysis tools that supports A12-8-7 (AUTOSAR C++14, e.g. 17-10) or [HIC++ v4.0 12.5.7](https://www.perforce.com/resources/qac/high-integrity-cpp-coding-standard/special-member-functions). The rationale of the rule is that user declared assignment operators differ from built-in operators: they accept rvalues as parameters. Adding "&" prohibits rvalue parameters and ensures that calls can only be made on lvalue objects and not on temporaries. That is to avoid e.g. `func()  = other_obj`.

Comment: That's pretty interesting as well as Barry's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to add a `&` qualifier in this case.

The point is to prevent your class from being copy-assignable, period. The purpose of the `&` qualifier is to prevent an *rvalue* of your class from being copy-assignable (the `&` would prevent the copy assignment operator from being a viable function in this case). But that's not your goal here - you want *all* copy assignment to be ill-formed, so that's just:

```
MyType& operator=(MyType const&) = delete;
```

And complain to whomever wrote that static check.

---

The issue with:

```
MyType& operator=(MyType const&) & = delete;
```

is that extra precision on the operator you're deleting suggests an intent that isn't there. I immediately am led to wonder if somewhere later in the class, for some reason, you have:

```
MyType& operator=(MyType const&) && { ... }
```

And you don't, because that's silly.

Comment: If `MyType& operator=(MyType const&) & = delete;` is defined, whereas there is no definition about `MyType& operator=(MyType const&) &&`, does `MyType()=MyType()` compiles? And why?