# Why are literals and temporary variables not lvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue, lvalue

I've read that `lvalues` are "things with a defined storage location".

And also that literals and temporaries variables are not lvalues, but no reason is given for this statement.

Is it because literals and temporary variables do not have defined storage location? If yes, then where do they reside if not in memory?

I suppose there is some significance to "defined" in "defined storage location", if there is (or is not) please let me know.

Comment: It would be helpful if there is some good reference explaining lvalue and rvalues

Comment: I find an easier rule of thumb is that lvalues can be named and their address can be taken. Maybe that's what they meant by "things with a defined storage location". They have an address that can be obtained.

Comment: @pasha [Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

Comment: temporaries do not need a defined storage location by definition. Consider `a = foo();` there is no need to store the result of `foo()` anywhere but in `a`

Comment: _"I've read that lvalues are 'things with a defined storage location.'"_ That's an oversimplification, and the problem with oversimplifications is that they are, sometimes, wrong. You should find the proper definition instead.

Comment: @Blaze you could argue that this is covered by the as-if rule. You can still get that behavior with LValues.

Comment: @pasha, [amen!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues).

Comment: @Frank true that. It was more of an answer to the "if it's not in memory, where else can it be" bit, which is of course only touching this tangentially.

Comment: @Blaze, agreed 5 is stored in the operation, but operation itself should be stored in memory, right? (this makes sense if I think in terms of what Francois commented, they have an address that can be taken)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks for the reference, it might take some time for me to read and understand.

Comment: @pasha If the operand is cooked into the assembly, then it doesn't really have any storage. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/VNfo8t). Edit : I mean, it doesn't have any storage that's accessible from c++.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It was clear until I saw the comment in one of the answers by Jarod42 mentioning, const int& v = 5;, Does 5 have a storage in this case?

Comment: *Value category* is a property of an **expression**, not of a "variable", "literal" or some other entity, as has been stated many times already. There's no such thing as "temporary variables and literals are not lvalues" in C++. This wording makes no sense at all.

Comment: @pasha When you initialize a `const` reference with `5`, that reference has a name and using that name is an lvalue expression. Edit : Taking a reference to something is not the same as taking it's address.

Comment: @AnT Is it possible to craft an expression where a literal would be an lvalue? Same question with a temporary. If not, then "temporary variables and literals are not lvalues" is a simplification that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> And also that literals and temporaries variables are not lvalues, but no reason is given for this statement.

This is true for all temporaries and literals except for string literals.  Those are actually lvalues (which is explained below).

> Is it because literals and temporaries variables do not have defined storage location? If yes, then where do they reside if not in memory?

Yes.  The literal `2` doesn't actually exist; it is just a value in the source code.  Since it's a value, not an object, it doesn't have to have any memory associated to it. It can be hard coded into the assembly that the compiler creates, or it could be put somewhere, but since it doesn't have to be, all you can do is treat it as a pure value, not an object.

There is an exemption though and that is string literals.  Those actually have storage since a string literal is an array of `const char[N]`.  You can take the address of a string literal and a string literal can decay into a pointer, so it is an lvalue, even though it doesn't have a name.

Temporaries are also rvalues.  Even if they exist as objects, their storage location is ephemeral.  They only last until the end of the full expression they are in. You are not allowed to take their address and they also do not have a name.  They might not even exist: for instance, in

```
Foo a = Foo();
```

The `Foo()` can be removed and the code semantically transformed to

```
Foo a(); // you can't actually do this since it declares a function with that signature.
```

so now there isn't even a temporary object in the optimized code.

Comment: why do string literals have storage but not other? Is it because they can't be embedded in single assembly instruction?

Comment: @pasha Because C. In C, you can do nothing with a string literal other than working with its address. It has to be in memory. It has to have an address. So C++ adapted. This is really an edge case.

Comment: @pasha Unlike other literals strings don't have a single value.  Each character is a value and since you need to combine of them together they are stored in an array.  Because it is an array it is no longer an rvalue because it is an object.

Answer (score 10):

> Why are literals and temporary variables not lvalues?

I have two answers: because it wouldn't make sense (1) and because the Standard says so (2). Let's focus on (1).

> Is it because literals and temporaries variables do not have defined storage location?

This is a simplification that doesn't fit here. A simplification that would: literals and temporary are not lvalues because it wouldn't make sense to modify them<sup>1</sup>.

**What is the meaning of `5++`? What is the meaning of `rand() = 0`?** The Standard says that temporaries and literals are not lvalues so those examples are invalid. And every compiler developer is happier.

---

<sup>1)</sup> You can define and use user-defined types in a way where the modification of a temporary makes sense. This temporary would live until the evaluation of the full-expression. François Andrieux makes a nice analogy between calling `f(MyType{}.mutate())` on one hand and `f(my_int + 1)` on the other. I think the simplification holds still as `MyType{}.mutate()` can be *seen as* another temporary as `MyType{}` was, like `my_int + 1` can be *seen as* another `int` as `my_int` was. This is all semantics and opinion-based. The real answer is: (2) because the Standard says so.

Comment: Your reasoning is a little flawed.  Yes, modifying 5 is nonsense but you are allowed to modify temporaries of non built in types.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, so side effects can happen. I think the reasoning (a simplification, let us not forget) holds still: except for specific cases (user-defined types with side effects on modification, string literals, ...) it means nothing to modify a pr-value.

Comment: In C, which yes is a different language, you can indeed write `(int){ 5 }++` and that means something; yes there is a particular logic behind that, but it's a possible example of how the two reasons are interlinked - a literal not making sense as an lvalue is essentially down to design decisions made for the Standard - if the Standard *wanted* all values to be lvalues, they would be and it would make sense in that language as-designed.

Comment: Another reason this reasoning is flawed is that a string literal *is* an lvalue, but "a" = 0 doesn't make sense.

Comment: @prl Well, yes... like any other _constant_ lvalue (`"a"` has type `char const[2]`)... and this is completely outside of the scope of this answer. In the same vein, `const int n = 0; n = 1;` is illegal, but frankly I don't see where it plays within my explanation.

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of common misconceptions in the question and in the other answers; my answer hopes to address that.

The terms *lvalue* and *rvalue* are **expression categories**.  They are terms that apply to expressions. Not to objects.  (A bit confusingly, the official term for expression categories is "value categories" ! )

The term *temporary object* refers to objects. This includes objects of class type, as well as objects of built-in type. The term *temporary* (used as a noun) is short for *temporary object*.  Sometimes the standalone term *value* is used to refer to a temporary object of built-in type. These terms apply to objects, not to expressions.

The C++17 standard is more consistent in object terminology than past standards, e.g. see [conv.rval]/1.  It now tries to avoid saying *value* other than in the context *value of an expression*.

---

Now, why are there different expression categories?  A C++ program is made up of a collection of expressions, joined to each other with operators to make larger expressions; and fitting within a framework of declarative constructs.  These expressions create, destroy, and do other manipulations on objects.  Programming in C++ could be described as using expressions to perform operations with objects.

The reason that expression categories exist is to provide a framework for using expressions to express operations that the programmer intends.  For example way back in the C days (and probably earlier), the language designers figured that `3 = 5;` did not make any sense as part of a program so it was decided to limit what sort of expression can appear on the left-hand side of `=`, and have the compiler report an error if this restriction wasn't followed.

The term *lvalue* originated in those days, although now with the development of C++ there are a vast range of expressions and contexts where expression categories are useful, not just the left-hand side of an assignment operator.

Here is some valid C++ code: `std::string("3") = std::string("5");`.  This is conceptually no different from `3 = 5;`, however it is allowed. The effect is that a temporary object of type `std::string` and content `"3"` is created, and then that temporary object is modified to have content `"5"`, and then the temporary object is destroyed.   The language could have been designed so that the code `3 = 5;` specifies a similar series of events (but it wasn't).

---

Why is the `string` example legal but the `int` example not?

Every expression has to have a category. The category of an expression might not seem to have an obvious reason at first,  but the designers of the language have given each expression a category according to what they think is a useful concept to express and what isn't.

It's been decided that the sequence of events in `3 = 5;` as described above is not something anyone would want to do, and if someone did write such a thing then they probably made a mistake and meant something else, so the compiler should help out by giving an error message.

Now, the same logic might conclude that `std::string("3") = std::string("5")` is not something anyone would ever want to do either.  However another argument is that for some other class type, `T(foo) = x;` might actually be a worthwhile operation, e.g. because `T` might have a destructor that does something.  It was decided that banning this usage could be more harmful to a programmer's intentions than good.  (Whether that was a good decision or not is debatable; [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995463/should-implicitly-generated-assignment-operators-be-ref-qualified) for discussion).

---

Now we are getting closer to finally address your question :)

Whether or not there is memory or a storage location associated is not the rationale for expression categories any more.  In the *abstract machine* (more explanation of this below), every temporary object (this includes the one created by `3` in `x = 3;`) exists in memory.

As described earlier in my answer, a program consists of expressions that manipulate objects. Each expression is said to *designate* or *refer to* an object.

It's very common for other answers or articles on this topic to make the incorrect claim that an rvalue can only designate a temporary object,  or even worse , that an rvalue *is* a temporary object , or that a temporary object is an rvalue.   An expression is not an object,  it is something that occurs in source code for manipulating objects!

In fact a temporary object can be designated by an lvalue or an rvalue expression; and a non-temporary object can be designated by an lvalue or an rvalue expression.  They are separate concepts.

Now, there's an expression category rule that you can't apply `&` to an expression of the rvalue category.  The purpose of this rule and these categories is to avoid errors where a temporary object is used after it is destroyed.  For example:

```
int *p = &5;    // not allowed due to category rules
*p = 6;         // oops, dangling pointer
```

But you could get around this:

```
template<typename T> auto f(T&&t) -> T& { return t; }
// ...
int *p = f(5); // Allowed
*p = 6;        // Oops, dangling pointer, no compiler error message.
```

In this latter code, `f(5)` and `*p` are both lvalues that designate a temporary object. This is a good example of why the expression category rules exist;  by following the rules without a tricky workaround, then we would get an error for the code that tries to write through a dangling pointer.

Note that you can also use this `f` to find the memory address of a temporary object, e.g. `std::cout << &f(5);`

---

In summary, the questions you actually ask all mistakenly conflate expressions with objects. So they are non-questions in that sense. Temporaries are not lvalues, because objects are not expressions.

A valid but related question would be: "Why is the expression that creates a temporary object an rvalue (as opposed to being an lvalue?)"

To which the answer is as was discussed above: having it be an lvalue would increase the risk of creating dangling pointers or dangling references; and as in `3 = 5;`, would increase the risk of specifying redundant operations that the programmer probably didn't intend.

I repeat again that the expression categories are a design decision to help with programmer expressiveness;  not anything to do with memory or storage locations.

---

Finally, to the abstract machine and the *as-if rule*. C++ is defined in terms of an abstract machine, in which temporary objects have storage and addresses too. I gave an example earlier of how to print the address of a temporary object.

The *as-if rule* says that the output of the actual executable the compiler produces must only match the output that the abstract machine would.  The executable doesn't actually have to work in the same way as the abstract machine, it just has to produce the same result.

So for code like `x = 5;`  , even though a temporary object of value `5` has a memory location in the abstract machine;  the compiler doesn't have to allocate physical storage on the real machine.  It only has to ensure that `x` ends up having `5` stored in it and there are much easier ways to do this that don't involve extra storage being created.

The *as-if* rule applies to everything in the program, even though my example here only refers to temporary objects.  A non-temporary object could equally well be optimized out, e.g. `int x; int y = 5; x = y;  // other code that doesn't use y` could be changed to `int x = 5;`.

The same applies for class types without side-effects that would alter the program output. E.g. `std::string x = "foo"; std::cout << x;` can be optimized to `std::cout << "foo";` even though the lvalue `x` denoted an object with storage in the abstract machine.

Comment: +1 I always assumed the l and r in lvalue/rvalue stood for left and right in the context of an assignment. Is this correct? If so then I would write this very conspicuously in the answer since it's pretty much a very short and to-the-point answer to the question.

Comment: @Mehrdad, that is where the names come from, and that is what they originally meant, but then X3J11 introduced the notion of a modifiable lvalue and things got murkier.

Comment: @Mehrdad my second section addresses that (and I don't feel your suggestion would be a correct answer, let alone a complete one)

Comment: Another example of why it makes no sense to allow taking the address of a value: `assert(&5 == &5);` – assuming that `&5` was a legal expression, would or should this hold? Would it even be useful in some way to ask whether `&5 == &5`? I for one cannot possibly imagine what the point would be.

Comment: Nice answer (+1) but very easy to get lost (maybe it's just me) so I have the following observations 1)`lvalue`s and `rvalue`s  are expression categories, not strictly relate to temporary or non-temporary object and `In fact a temporary object can be designated by an lvalue or an rvalue expression; and a non-temporary object can be designated by an lvalue or an rvalue expression.` It is clear from your answer what `lvalues` and `rvalues` are not, but could you point out (more clearly maybe) what they are then? 

2) Can you explain the syntax `-> T& { return t; }`?

Comment: 3) You showed on how to get an `lvalue` from a temporary object (the less obvious case) but can you make explicit also the other cases: hot to get `lvalue` (and `rvalue`) from temporary (and non temporary) objects ? In some of them are obvious but in this way the whole picture is clear

Comment: @FrancescoBoi (1) lvalues and rvalues are expressions, (2) trailing return type, (3) lvalue designating temporary is already shown; rvalue designating temporary: `int()`,  lvalue designating non-temporary: `x`, rvalue designating non-temporary: `std::move(x)`

Comment: 1) Yeah I got they are expressions categories and that they are defined apriori (aren't they?) by the language designers but how were they defined? I mean they went through every possible expression and decided what expression is what or there are some common "characteristics" ? And what are the consequences of an expression being an `rvalue` rather than an `lvalue`? If you have an external reference that explains clearly it is good too.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi the c++ standard might be a good place to read, the Expressions chapter starts off with this topic

Comment: I'll check it but I think it requires an advanced level even beyond a good C++ programmer.

Answer (score 5):

`lvalue` stands for **locator value** and represents an object that occupies some identifiable location in memory.

The term **locator value** is also used [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

> C
>
> The C programming language followed a similar taxonomy, except that
>   the role of assignment was no longer significant: C expressions are
>   categorized between "lvalue expressions" and others (functions and
>   non-object values), where "lvalue" means an expression that identifies
>   an object, a "locator value"[4].

Everything that is not an `lvalue` is by exclusion an `rvalue`. Every expression is either an `lavalue` or `rvalue`.

Originally `lvalue` term was used in C to indicate values that can stay on the left side of assignment operator. However with the `const` keywork this changed. Not all `lvalues` can be assigned to. Those that can are called `modifiable lvalues`.

> And also that literals and temporaries variables are not lvalues, but
>   no reason is given for this statement.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13735632/1714692) literals can be `lvalues` in some cases.

- **literals of scalar types** are `rvalue` because they are of known size and are very likely to be embedded directly into the machine commands on the given hardware architecture. What would be the memory location of `5`?
- On the contrary, strangely enough, **string literals** are `lvalues` since they have unpredictable size and there is no other way to represent them apart from as objects in memory.

An `lvalue` can be converted to an `rvalue`. For example in the following instructions

```
int a =5;
int b = 3;
int c = a+b;
```

the operator `+` takes two `rvalues`. So `a` and `b` are converted to `rvalues` before getting summed. Another example of conversion:

```
int c = 6;
&c = 4; //ERROR: &c is an rvalue
```

On the contrary **you cannot convert an `rvalue` to an `lvalue`**.

However you **can** produce a valid `lvalue` from an `rvalue` for example:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2};
int* p = &arr[0];
*(p + 1) = 10;   // OK: p + 1 is an rvalue, but *(p + 1) is an lvalue
```

In C++11 rvalues reference are related to the move constructor and move assignment operator.

You can find more details in [this clear and well-explained post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/).

Comment: I added another link in the answer check the `C` paaragraph: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: `"Hello world\n"` has a definite address.

Comment: It's `&"Hello world\n"`  see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c19f1a7fa216cdc5

Comment: "On the contrary you cannot convert an rvalue to an lvalue"  - yes you can: write `template<typename T> auto f(T&& t) -> T& { return t; }`   , then calling `f` on an rvalue will yield an lvalue referring to the same object. E.g. `cout << &f(5);`

Comment: @M.M Honestly those lines are not really clear to me so I cannot modify my answer to explain them. If you have some reference I will gladly read it and try to modify my answer accordingly. Also feel free to modify my answer yourself if worth it.

Comment: @NathanOliver not really, That is the address of a (possibly different) copy of the same string. At least in C?

Comment: I think it just confuses the language-design issue to use the term "hidden lvalue".  The fact that most ISAs lack floating-point immediates is just an implementation detail.  That might make a fun fact footnote, but doesn't belong in your bullet list.  In C++, `5.5` is purely an rvalue, even though (if it doesn't get optimized away or changed by constant-propagation) it will probably end up in read-only static storage.  But `x * 2.0` will be compiled as `x+x` by most good compilers on most ISAs.  Where's your "hidden lvalue" now?  It's just an asm implementation detail, unrelated to C++ rules.

Comment: You're still bolding this bogus term "hidden `lvalues`" without any double-quotes to indicate that it's not a real term, and doesn't mean anything in C++ terms.  It *just* an implementation detail, and doesn't even apply to all FP constants.  (e.g. the `2.0 * x` compiling as `x+x` example).

Comment: @Wilson The Q is tagged as C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver You mean to say it is not the case in C++ also? That's news to me

Comment: @Wilson In C++ `"test"` is required to be an lvalue.  I'm not sure what C has to say about it (but I expect it would be the same).  Since the Q is tagged as C++ though it doesn't really matter, since the answers need to be correct for C++

Comment: @Wilson C doesn't have references, let alone rvalue references, there's only one `T` object there. All `f` is doing is changing the value category of it's argument

Comment: done.  AnT's answer is pretty much fine, though: it already says "(even though the language does not expose them as such) right after that.  Unlike your answer where you had that term highlighted and without quotes around the "hidden", making it sound more like a real thing.

Answer (score 3):

> Where do they reside if not in memory?

Of course they reside in memory<sup>*</sup>, there's no way around it. The question is, can your program determine where exactly in memory do they reside. In other words, is your program allowed to take the address of the thing in question.

In a simple example `a = 5` the value of five, or an instruction representing an assignment of the value of five, is somewhere in memory. However, you cannot take the address of five, because `int *p = &5` is illegal.

Note that string literals are an exception from the "not an lvalue" rule, because `const char *p = "hello"` produces an address of a string literal.

---

<sup>*</sup> However, it may not necessarily be *data* memory. In fact, they may not even be represented as a constant in the program memory: for example, an assignment `short a; a = 0xFF00` could be represented as a an assignment of `0xFF` in the upper octet, and clearing out the lower octet in memory.

Comment: You can take address of an `lvalue`: `&++i` or `&std::endl`

Comment: *"you cannot take the address of five"*. `const int& v = 5;` is legal though.

Comment: @Jarod42 That is not taking the address of `5` though.  That materialized a temporary `int` object with the value of `5` and binds the reference to that object, not to the `5`.

Comment: Or `XOR AX,AX; DEC AH`  ... or lots of other strategies.